# jQuery, manipulate dynamically created element in callback of a click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, dynamically-generated, removeclass

I have a mobile menu with this (simplified) html

```
<ul id="mobile_menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="#">Menu with Submenu</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Submenu item 1</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Submenu item 2</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item enu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Submenu item 3</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub-Submenu item 1</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub-Submenu item 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">menu item 2</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">menu item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I create an helper element to close submenus in mobile devices.
I create it in a function, like this:

```
var mainli_a =  jQuery('#mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children > a');

mainli_a.on('touchstart click', function(e){

                    "use strict";
                    var link = jQuery(this);
                    if (link.parent().hasClass('active')) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        link.parent().addClass('active')
                        link.parent().append('<span class="closesubmenu"> </span>');  // here I create the element

                        e.preventDefault();
                        return false; 
                    }
                });
```

The element I'm speaking about is the span.closesubmenu

Then, on a click on it, i want to remove a class to its parent element, and then remove the element .closesubmenu itself.

This is how i try:

```
   jQuery('body').on('touchstart click', 'span.closesubmenu', function(e){

            jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('active', 0, 'linear', function(){
                 jQuery(this).remove(); // this does not work
            });

    });
```

It does not matter wich manipulation i try in the callback to closesubmenu. 
it does not work.

It only work only like this:

```
 jQuery('body').on('touchstart click', 'span.closesubmenu', function(e){

         jQuery(this).remove(); // this works    

    });
```

Furthermore, if I just put 2 manipulations on 2 lines, only the first one works:

```
 jQuery('body').on('touchstart click', 'span.closesubmenu', function(e){

         jQuery(this).remove(); // this works  
         jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('active'); // this does not work 

    });

 jQuery('body').on('touchstart click', 'span.closesubmenu', function(e){

         jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('active'); // this works  
         jQuery(this).remove(); // this does not work 

    });
```

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:**

I tried also as suggested in answers, to store the element in a var to use in the callback, like this:

```
            jQuery('body').on('touchstart click', 'span.closesubmenu', function(e){
                var self = this;
                jQuery(self).parent().removeClass('active', 0, 'linear', function(){
                    jQuery(self).remove();
                });
        });
```

But it is not working.

**UPDATE 2**: jsFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/bluantinoo/yr4gdjdz/3/

**UPDATE 3**: Thanks to David (chosen answer) this is the correct and working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bluantinoo/yr4gdjdz/6/

Comment: `var self = this`?

Comment: Where's the associated html? As per [mcve]

Comment: In the `removeClass()` callback function, `this` is the parent, not `span.closesubmenu`.

Comment: I added the associated html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are all these parameters you're passing to `.removeClass()`?

```
jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('active', 0, 'linear', function(){
    jQuery(this).remove();
});
```

[It's only expecting the class name(s).](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)  And it's not an asynchronous operation with a callback.  Just remove the class(es) and then remove the element:

```
jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('active');
jQuery(this).remove();
```

[Example.](https://jsfiddle.net/L6aobax6/1/)

Comment: I tried that (I updated the question) but it's not working

Comment: @bluantinoo: Define "not working".  When you debug this, where specifically does it fail?  For example, the selector filters for `'span.closesubmenu'`, but the original HTML doesn't have any elements which match that.  Have you confirmed those elements are being added successfully?  The original HTML also appears to be malformed, so the jQuery DOM traversal might not be doing what you expect until you fix the HTML.  "Not working" doesn't really describe the problem, debug it.

Comment: Hi David, yes, the element is correctly added. At each click a span.closesubmenu is added. But it is never removed. Not working means that what should happen is just not happening. No errors in console.

Comment: Can you provide a complete jsFiddle which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @bluantinoo: Upon further inspection, what are all those parameters you're passing to `removeClass()`?  That's not an asynchronous operation.

Comment: @bluantinoo: I've updated the answer with a link to a working example.

Comment: I've added the jsfiddle. But you're answer is correct. When i tried that and it was not working there was for sure some other error I did not see.

Comment: @bluantinoo: I've also taken the liberty to update your jsFiddle just now: https://jsfiddle.net/yr4gdjdz/5/